# How do I return the switch statement inside a do while loop using an instance method?

Tags: java

```
public void select()
{



do
{
  switch(info)
   {
     case'1':
     case'a':
       return System.out.println("Hello");
     case'2':
     case'b':
       return selection = 'b';
     default:
       return System.out.println("Close");
   }
 }while(info != 'b');
}
```

So what would be the proper syntax and is this the even possible to do. New to Java

Comment: I forgot to add that the case is user input via a Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: The code is not very close to compiling. What would you want the method to do?

Comment: You can't return anything from a `void` method. Also, you don't update `info` in the loop. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: It's suppose to take in user input and select an option from either case 1 or 2 with 1,a or 2,b as the input and than return the printout

Comment: return selection = 'b'; should be return info = 'b';

Comment: Only non-void methods support being returned from - this has nothing to do with loops. That method returns  'void' , however,  so even that is not possible. It is also not possible to use the result of a void method call in an expression. And the select variable is not declared..  But such is already so incorrect.

Comment: Since all cases execute a return, the loop is meaningless.

Comment: so what should the method be instead? what is the proper syntax

Comment: @Jets Consider a tutorial / introductory book,  as there is more than 'syntax'  to  learn.

Comment: I think you are new to programming, not only new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

First, the loop is not needed, you can delete that. And you are using return statements wrongly. You cannot return

```
System.out.println();
```

Also, your method is declared to return `void` which means nothing. That means your return statement doesn't need anything else,just the word return.

```
 return;
```

So my advice is that print the stuff first, and then `return`. And you should really read Java for Dummies, by Barry Burd.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all you **can't** return anything from a `void` method, instead change it to `char` for example:

```
public char select () {
    //read user input
    char userInput = '1'; //change it as you wish or read from console
    switch (userInput) {
        case '1':
        case 'a':
            return 'a';
        case '2':
        case 'b':
            return 'b';
        //... and so on
        default:
            return '0'; //Or anything you want (but it MUST be a char (at least for my code, if you change it to String, you can return a word or well... a String)).
    }
}
```

Then on main method (or the method which called `select()`) you add:

```
char selection;
selection = select();
System.out.println(selection);
```

If you want to add the `switch` into a loop (`do-while` as in your question), then you might want to do it this way on main method:

```
char selection;
do {
    selection = select();
    System.out.println(selection);
} while (selection != '0');
```

However I strongly recommend you to read Java Docs: [Switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and [Returning a Value from a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) which is actually what you're trying to achieve.

From second link you can confirm what I said before (on the 1st line of my answer and as some other users stated on comments)

> Any method declared void doesn't return a value.